# Need help with GeForce 8400 GS in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics

I have a Dell Optiplex 790 and have installed a GeForce 8400GS card.   I installed the Ubuntu base from the mini.iso file and added the LXDE-core desktop environment.  Everything works with the Intel integrated card, but there are a few symptoms that something is a bit off with that connection (screen is pixely for a moment after logging in and at times there is a wave-like behavior).  The main issue is with the GeForce card.  When I boot-up with the cable connected to it, the monitor acts like nothing is connected  (screen is black, light is blinking).  If I move the cable to the integrated card, I can see the desktop on the monitor.

After I first installed the OS, the card worked, but everything was extremely slow to respond, like I had only 256mb of ram installed (there are 8GB installed. with over 7gb free).  I concluded something was amiss with the drivers.  Here are the steps I have taken to resolve, but haven't been able to fix it:

- Blacklisted the Nouveau driver (which was what originally showed when I did`sudo lshw -c display`.  Now it shows Nvidia.
- Opened TTY and did: `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` then `sudo service lightdm stop`, then `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers`, then `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get install nvidia-340`
- I then rebooted and went to Additional drivers and made sure the 340 card was selected.
- I rebooted.  It didn't work.  I then opened Nvidia Server Settings and installed Prime.  It showed Nvidia as the selected card.  I then did `Prime-Select query` and it showed Nvidia.

I think that is all the steps I have done so far.  It appears that the system sees the cards, sees the driver, is thinking the Nvidia card is the one I am using (which may explain why things are a bit hinky with the Intel card), but I can't get the system to actually use the Nvidia card.  I am sure I am missing something basic and important....I just can't figure it out.

---

10/05/19 Responding to N0rbert's suggestion, I tried plugging in the DVI cable (there are only DVI and VGA options on this card).  The monitor was recognized, but didn't wake-up until the start-up process got to the desktop.  No splash screen or anything else.  Also, when I look at Monitor Settings, it only shows the DVI monitor, even after plugging in the VGA cable as well.  I know the VGA works as it worked at the beginning, just really slow (like the computer had only 256mb of ram installed).  In addition, when opening a program (like Firefox), it is unrolling the window, rather than just appearing, if that makes sense.

---

Responding to OldFred
Thanks for the suggestion!

### I am wanting to use the card as it will allow me to use 2 monitors.  It worked well for 16.04.  I am having difficulty after upgrading.

Update 10/7/19 2:42p

When connecting the DVI cable to the GEForce card, I am able to use the integrated VGA at the same time.  I am wondering if there is a correlation between that and the GeForce card VGA not working.

Comment: I would recommend to connect DVI or HDMI cable directly to Nvidia card port and retry. Are you sure that Nvidia card is operating normally on hardware level?

Comment: Just use the Intel Video. This says Intel is 213 and 8400 GS is 113 on comparison scale. https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/compare/Intel-HD-2000-vs-GeForce-8400-GS/3264vs73

Comment: I have a test PC with an Nvidia Geforce 8300. The only Nvidia driver I could get to work on it was the 304 driver, and I had to patch it using the procedure on this page: https://adufray.com/blog/  The 340 driver was recommended by the system, but it did not work well at all.

Comment: Thanks Organic Marble.  I will give that a shot.  304 was listed as an option, but I chose the 340.  Did your system offer 304?  Did you try it without the patch?  If so, what happened?

Comment: Without the patch it would crash horribly locking the system up and requiring a fsck on the next boot.